# Mark iCal event as "all day" with Perl module Data::ICal

Tags: perl, cpan, icalendar

There is a huge Perl module [Data::ICal](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aICal) that makes it possible to create iCal files that can be added to Calendar app on mac (they also can be added to a lot of other programmes).

I've used [Data::ICal](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aICal) and I have written a simple script that creates iCal file. I've added it the Calendar app and it works fine.

Here is the listing:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

use Data::ICal;
use Data::ICal::Entry::Event;
use Date::ICal;
use File::Slurp;

my $calendar = Data::ICal->new();

my $ical_date = Date::ICal->new(
    year => 2013,
    month => 9,
    day => 6,
);

my $event = Data::ICal::Entry::Event->new();
$event->add_properties(
    summary => "my party",
    description => "I'll cry if I want to",
    dtstart => $ical_date->ical(),
);

$calendar->add_entry($event);

write_file('sample.ics', $calendar->as_string);
```

But now I want to mark this event as lasting for the whole day. I've grepped throw the module source docs and code, but I havn't found the way to do it.

How can I mark this event as lasting for the whole day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [description](http://www.innerjoin.org/iCalendar/all-day-events.html) on innerjoin, all you have to do is set `dtstart` and `dtend` as `YYYYMMDD` (no hours or below) where start is the day (of your party) and end the next day.

At least with thunderbird/sunbird this works flawlessly:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use Data::ICal;
use Data::ICal::Entry::Event;
use File::Slurp;

my $calendar = Data::ICal->new();

my $event = Data::ICal::Entry::Event->new();
$event->add_properties(
    summary     => "my party",
    description => "I'll cry if I want to",
    dtstart     => "20130906",
    dtend       => "20130907",
);

$calendar->add_entry($event);

write_file('sample.ics', $calendar->as_string);
```

Comment: Yep! It perfectly solves my problem. Thank you. (Actually I don't like this solution because it looks like hack, but it works and I because I have no idea of other solution I will take this code)